# Typescript file-naming conventions

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions

I'm looking for the Typescript file-naming conventions, specifically for a file which stores only types and interfaces.

Now, I've found a couple of Typescript Coding Convention projects on GitHub, and they even refer to file-naming conventions [here](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/styleguide/styleguide.md#filename) and [here](http://unional.github.io/typescript-blackbook/docs/guidelines/files_and_folders/naming-convention). But none of them refers to the specific file that I'm interested in, namely - a file which stores only types and interfaces.

For all it matters, within my project this file serves for both internal usage and external API.

Comment: Not too sure there is a good answer for what the file name should be (I'd say follow the conventions of your project if applicable), but if the file contains only type information, giving it a `.d.ts` extension will indicate that.

Comment: @CRice: Thanks, but that's what `rimraf` (building the project) does in (some of the) output files. So I'm not sure that naming one of my source files in a similar manner would be a good idea. Am I wrong here somewhere?

Comment: There certainly is no right or wrong. If you prefer something like camelCase, make sure to turn on `--forceConsistentCasingInFileNames`, e.g. if you work with linux and windows. Also, if the types are part of the public API, choose `.ts` instead of `.d.ts`, otherwise you need an extra build step.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I get tired of spending time researching for things like this so I have decided to go with the following practice.

`interfaces` folder for files that contain interfaces
file naming convention: `file.interface.ts`

`types` folder for files that contain types
file naming convention: `file.type.ts`

Answer (score 1):

we usually go for "index.d.ts" and have multiple spaced throughout the project.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what `rimraf` (building the project) does in (some of the) output files. So I'm not sure that naming one of my source files in a similar manner would be a good idea. Am I wrong here somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

In general I follow Google's styleguige.
Module namespace imports are **lowerCamelCase** while files are **snake_case**.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html